# How to create an example for the complex statement?

Tags: c

There is a complex statement in my textbook:
`int (*f(float (*)(long),char *))(double)`; 
I want to create an example for illustrating how to use this statement, although I understand the meaning of the statement, it's hard for me to write the example. Can anyone help me?
`P.S.`: `C language`.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, I want to get a complete code (C programming) for illustrating how to use the complex statement in C program.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Come up with your own proposal, and specific questions about it. As it stands the question is much too broad, as there are many many ways to use this declaration

Comment: pointer functions as parameters can be confusing looking when they aren't explicitly defined in a declaration.  Start with the inside parenthesis and work your way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int (*f(float (*)(long),char *))(double)
```

*f* is a function that has 2 parameters of type

```
float (*)(long),  << pointer to function long=>float
char *            << string
```

and returns

```
(int)(*)(double) << a pointer to a function double=>int
```

Comment: Hi, alinsoar, thank you for replying. Can you write the complete code to illustrate how to use the statement in C program?

Comment: Alinsoar did a pretty good job breaking down the declaration and doing everything except literally doing your homework for you.  Perhaps you should re-read his post and attempt to write your own code.